# Send mail if service bus count becomes zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicebus

I am sending a file of data to service bus queue and while retrieving data I am getting active message count by

```
queue.MessageCountDetails.ActiveMessageCount;
```

if this count is zero, send mail to a user that data has been uploaded.
When SendReport() method hits then `queueclient` got message and it hits to again `Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>`. User should get one report for each file.
But in my case report has been created for multiple times.
how can I send one report per file?

Comment: Please provide more info, very hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

Very vague but are you trying to send chunks of a file in multiple messages? If so, a better approach is to use the [Claim Check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/claim-check) pattern instead.

With this, you will process just one message from service bus, fetch the file from the external store and send an email just once.

Comment: Ya! You are right but I cannot store data in database

Comment: I appended a bit called IsLastRecord with each file and checked this bit is true or false while retrieving data from a service bus and stored that data in Collection. When I get that bit true I send mail to the user with this data

Comment: That does work **but** do note the payload size limitations per message which would lead to many messages for larger files. Also, to ensure FIFO, you might want to consider using [Message Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) as well with one session id per file.